# if else block is not working properly in batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p filename=please enter name of file..:

echo "%filename%"

(
 echo %filename% 
 if exist { C:\Windows\System32\%filename% }
 (
 wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\%filename%" get version 
 wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\%filename%" get path
 )
else
 (
 wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\%filename%" get version
 wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\%filename%" get path
 )



) >output.txt

start notepad.exe output.txt
```

I have made this batch file to search files,name the files,get the version of files and print the path of the existing file in a text file.but if else block is not working properly. Help me and thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Replace `{` and `}` by `"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A) `Set /p` has quotes to allow long filenames, as good practice.
B) `if exist` line has quotes for the same reason, plus the parenthesis is on the end of the line
C) `) else (` must be on one line

```
@echo off
set /p "filename=please enter name of file..: "

echo "%filename%"

(
 echo %filename% 
 if exist "C:\Windows\System32\%filename%" (
      echo block 1
   wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\%filename%" get version 
   wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\%filename%" get path
 ) else (
      echo block 2
   wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\%filename%" get version
   wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\%filename%" get path
 )

) >output.txt

start notepad.exe output.txt
```

Comment: An explanation of the changes needed would also be helpful, rather than just a lump of  code

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Yes, my liege.  ;)

Comment: Crackin' - if OP just copies and pastes the whole lot, they won't learn anything. A description of what was wrong and needed changing will prevent them creating a similar question in 10 minutes

Comment: @smokeyPHP. Thanks for the reply. I just want that if a file is present in system32 folder then code should skip the else block but it is not happening in practically. Also i want to generalise the code to search any file present in all the folders in windows.

Comment: Try the code above - see the two new echo statements.  You will find that it only executes one block.

Comment: @foxidrive- The code is working as earlier. but the commands in either blocks still getting executed and since their is no file named url.dll(for example) is present in drivers folder the result is showing as no instance(s) available. Also " 'else' is not recognized as internal or external command " getting popped up on cmd prompt.

Comment: @biz00ka - Add another if: `) else if exist "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\%filename%" (`

Comment: @biz00ka - There is no need for 2 calls to WMIC. A single call can retrieve both version and path: `wmic datafile ... get path, version`

Comment: @all-Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: +1, I once answered a similar question, but it was also about other issues, same as this one. Pity, no one seems to have asked specifically about how to properly use if/else so that we could use it as a reference question for duplicate ones. :)