# BATCH File if else always executes the else, What is the correct syntax when using do

Tags: batch-file

I am doing a check whether a network drive exists if it does i copy over text files to it otherwise i echo that it does not exist

my problem is that it executes the if but also always executes the else every time
I have double checked matching brackets and searched for the syntax, I am wondering if it has something to do with the `do`

Please see code below

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=inv.filie.log
call :LOG >> %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
E:

echo.
echo *** Date: %DATE:/=-%  Time:%TIME::=-% *** 
echo.


CD "E:\Ftp\Clients\OUT_TEST\INV\"

echo.
echo.
echo Moving Files to Test:

For %%G in (*.txt) do ( 
    if exist z:\ (
        COPY /Y "%%G" "Z:\Outgoing\" 
        MOVE /Y "%%G" "E:\Ftp\Clients\OUT_TEST\INV\Archive\"
    )
    else (
        echo Direcotry Z:\ for test is offline
    )
)

echo.
echo.
echo *** Task complete ***
```

And the output of inv.file.log is

```
*** Date: 2018-05-25  Time: 8-11-53.89 *** 

Moving Files to Test AS2:
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) moved.
Direcotry Z:\ for test is offline


*** Task complete ***
```

As can be seen above it always echo's the line `Direcotry Z:\ for test is offline`

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: @GOTO0: You think correctly. `) else (` is required to be on one physical line.

Comment: Possible duplicate targets [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005585/if-else-block-is-not-working-properly-in-batch-file) (too broad) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347536/batch-if-else-not-working) (answered in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid syntax, the parentheses and `else` must be on the same line.

The following script:

```
@echo off
if exist c:\ (
    echo if true
)
else (
    echo if false
)
```

will generate:

```
if true
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
if false
```

because it sees the first closing parenthesis as the *end* of the `if` statement.

I'm not sure *why* you're not seeing the error unless you invoke your script with a `2>nul:` - this would throw away the error and you'de simply see:

```
if true
if false
```

---

In any case, the *correct* way to do this is to format the `if` statement correctly. In your case, that would be:

```
for %%g in (*.txt) do ( 
    if exist z:\ (
        copy /y "%%g" "z:\outgoing\" 
        move /y "%%g" "e:\ftp\clients\out_test\inv\archive\"
    ) else (
        echo Directory z:\ for test is offline.
    )
)
```

You could *possibly* also make it better by *not* checking for the existence of `z:` for every single file. You may find that this works better:

```
if not exist z:\ (
    echo Directory z:\ for test is offline.
) else (
    copy /y *.txt "z:\outgoing\" 
    move /y *.txt "e:\ftp\clients\out_test\inv\archive\"
)
```

Note that I'm not saying it *is* better since you have access to more context than I. This is a decision you should make based on a complete picture.